# AMap3DMap crashed in 5.2.1

Tags: ios

I see this crash in my app that application did enterBackground that the AMap3DMa's version was 5.2.1

```
1libGPUSupportMercury.dylib0x1911a8f94<redacted>
2AGXGLDriver0x195c641bc_gldUpdateDispatch
3libGPUSupportMercury.dylib0x1911a9f44_gpusSubmitDataBuffers
4AGXGLDriver0x195c6577c_gldUpdateDispatch
5GLEngine0x196478c9c<redacted>
6GLEngine0x196455fc4<redacted>
7GLEngine0x1963fa2c4<redacted>
8GLKit0x18b7b74fc-[GLKView _deleteFramebuffer] + 152
9GLKit0x18b7b6dc4-[GLKView dealloc] + 92
10LSWearable0x100a5b988-[MAMapRender dealloc] + 216
11libobjc.A.dylib0x1800c5fe0(anonymous    namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 704
12UIKit0x187528668-[UIView dealloc] + 1644
13LSWearable0x1004e5778-[xxxx .cxx_destruct] (xxxxx.m:155)
14libobjc.A.dylib0x1800aaf10object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
15libobjc.A.dylib0x1800b77f4_objc_destructInstance + 92
16libobjc.A.dylib0x1800b7858_object_dispose + 28
17UIKit0x1878c7d28-[UIResponder dealloc] + 156
18UIKit0x1876aef9c-[UIViewController dealloc] + 1784
19LSWearable0x1004d3890-[xxxx dealloc] (xxxxx:913)
20CoreFoundation0x181551fe4-[__NSArrayI dealloc] + 84
21LSWearable0x10012f75c___43-[xxxxx callbackWillEndPedPath]_block_invoke (xxxxx.m:181)
22libdispatch.dylib0x1804fe1fc__dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
23libdispatch.dylib0x1804fe1bc__dispatch_client_callout + 16
24libdispatch.dylib0x180502d68__dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
    25CoreFoundation0x181622810___CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
26CoreFoundation0x1816203fc___CFRunLoopRun + 1660
27CoreFoundation0x18154e2b8_CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
28GraphicsServices0x183002198_GSEventRunModal + 180
29UIKit0x1875957fc-[UIApplication _run] + 684
30UIKit0x187590534_UIApplicationMain + 208
31LSWearable0x10087ec00_main (main.m:16)
32libdyld.dylib0x1805315b8_start + 4
```

Comment: Please add some more details on the problem you want to fix

Comment: that crash happened in enter background